Eclipse Ditto on Docker Swarm | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "gateway" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:44
Challenges Running Eclipse Ditto on Docker Swarm
Eclipse Ditto on Docker Swarm | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "gateway" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:44 | [error] 33#33: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
I'm trying to run Eclipse Ditto on Docker Swarm, initially, I was able to successfully run Ditto using the provided docker-compose.yml file in Docker (not Swarm mode) without modifying the nginx.conf file.
I made some adjustments to the docker-compose.yml file to work in Docker Swarm :

Commented out restart: always;
Commented out healthcheck section;
Commented out volumes for the swagger-ui service, since volumes are not be suitable for Swarm, I will configure it later;
Replaced volumes for the nginx service with configs, to mount nginx files;

I'm encountering an issue where the nginx service is not recongizing gateway service, here is its logs:
docker service logs -f my_stack_nginx
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | 2024/06/18 15:44:39 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "gateway" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:44
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "gateway" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:44

the line 44 from nginx.conf file :
39     ...
40     # connections api using devops user configured in Ditto
41    location /api/2/connections {
42      include nginx-cors.conf;
43
44      proxy_pass                    http://gateway:8080;
45      proxy_http_version            1.1;
46      proxy_set_header              Host                $http_host;
47      proxy_set_header              X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
48      proxy_set_header              X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
49      proxy_set_header              X-Forwarded-User    $remote_user;
50
51      proxy_set_header Connection  '';
52      chunked_transfer_encoding    off;
53      proxy_buffering              off;
54      proxy_cache                  off;
55    }
56    ...

and when I send a request from Postman, ex : GET http://localhost:8080/api/2/things/ with ditto:ditto in Authorization, I get this as output :
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

The nginx logs :
docker service logs -f my_stack_nginx
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | 2024/06/18 15:44:39 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "gateway" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:44
my_stack_nginx.1.rtextyzpzpsl@docker-desktop    | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "gateway" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:44
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | 2024/06/18 15:47:55 [error] 33#33: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/2/things/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.1.13:8080/api/2/things/", host: "localhost:8080"
my_stack_nginx.1.64bhclqugkeq@docker-desktop    | 10.0.0.2 - ditto [18/Jun/2024:15:47:55 +0000] "GET /api/2/things/ HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.39.0"

Additional Information:

Windows 10, 8GB RAM and CPU :

Name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9400H CPU @ 2.50GHz
Number Of Cores : 4
Number Of Logical Processors : 8

Docker :
Client:
  Version:    26.1.1

  Context:    default

  Debug Mode: false

  Plugins:

      buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)

      Version:  v0.14.0-desktop.1

      Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-buildx.exe

      compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)

      Version:  v2.27.0-desktop.2

      Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-compose.exe

      debug: Get a shell into any image or container (Docker Inc.)

      Version:  0.0.29

      Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-debug.exe

      dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc.)

      Version:  v0.1.2

      Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-dev.exe

      extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc.)

      Version:  v0.2.23

      Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-extension.exe

      feedback: Provide feedback, right in your terminal! (Docker Inc.)

      Version:  v1.0.4

      Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-feedback.exe

      init: Creates Docker-related starter files for your project (Docker Inc.)

      Version:  v1.1.0

      Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-init.exe

      sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc.)

      Version:  0.6.0

      Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-sbom.exe

      scout: Docker Scout (Docker Inc.)

      Version:  v1.8.0

      Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-scout.exe

Server:
  Containers: 34

      Running: 9

      Paused: 0

      Stopped: 25

  Images: 53

  Server Version: 26.1.1

  Storage Driver: overlay2

      Backing Filesystem: extfs

      Supports d_type: true

      Using metacopy: false

      Native Overlay Diff: true

      userxattr: false

  Logging Driver: json-file

  Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs

  Cgroup Version: 1

  Plugins:

      Volume: local

      Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay

      Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local splunk syslog

  Swarm: active

      NodeID: mahw8hl8i23zzwm7v2i78vaq7

      Is Manager: true

      ClusterID: ijzjixaizfhrhv754v8ir4fdy

      Managers: 1

      Nodes: 1

      Data Path Port: 4789

      Orchestration:

          Task History Retention Limit: 5

  Raft:

      Snapshot Interval: 10000

      Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0

      Heartbeat Tick: 1

      Election Tick: 10

  Dispatcher:

      Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds

  CA Configuration:

      Expiry Duration: 3 months

      Force Rotate: 0

  Autolock Managers: false

  Root Rotation In Progress: false

  Node Address: 192.168.65.3

  Manager Addresses:

      192.168.65.3:2377

  Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc

  Default Runtime: runc

  Init Binary: docker-init

  containerd version: e377cd56a71523140ca6ae87e30244719194a521

  runc version: v1.1.12-0-g51d5e94

  init version: de40ad0

  Security Options:

      seccomp

          Profile: unconfined

  Kernel Version: 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2

  Operating System: Docker Desktop

  OSType: linux

  Architecture: x86_64

  CPUs: 8

  Total Memory: 3.721GiB

  Name: docker-desktop

  ID: ec241856-9f66-4d6c-908f-3ff0184e56b5

  Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker

  Debug Mode: false

  HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128

  HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128

  No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal

  Labels:

      com.docker.desktop.address=npipe://\\.\pipe\docker_cli

  Experimental: false

  Insecure Registries:

      hubproxy.docker.internal:5555

      127.0.0.0/8

  Live Restore Enabled: false



The docker-compose.yml file : https://pastebin.com/nbKcXjDc
The services are runnig :
the services are runnig : 
docker service ls
ID             NAME                     MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE                                PORTS
idgug4xs4u6g   my_stack_connectivity    replicated   1/1        eclipse/ditto-connectivity:latest
16uijjs8vpeb   my_stack_ditto-ui        replicated   1/1        eclipse/ditto-ui:latest
5pd7diz1uz1i   my_stack_gateway         replicated   1/1        eclipse/ditto-gateway:latest         *:8081->8080/tcp
jkkfj363z20o   my_stack_mongodb         replicated   1/1        mongo:6.0                            *:27017->27017/tcp
mc58254lk2h2   my_stack_nginx           replicated   1/1        nginx:1.26-alpine                    *:8080->80/tcp
kn5evgmkpvdw   my_stack_policies        replicated   1/1        eclipse/ditto-policies:latest
t4agxrku1991   my_stack_swagger-ui      replicated   1/1        swaggerapi/swagger-ui:v5.9.1
v42cz47b90qu   my_stack_things          replicated   1/1        eclipse/ditto-things:latest
xyoa5siftouk   my_stack_things-search   replicated   1/1        eclipse/ditto-things-search:latest

Inspect ditto-net-swarm network :
> docker network ls

NETWORK ID     NAME                               DRIVER    SCOPE
e661fefa2fba   bridge                             bridge    local
afa0a7369fed   docker_default                     bridge    local
636762e55a0e   host                               host      local
ipd43285nlar   ingress                            overlay   swarm
miy4fnbluu70   my_stack_ditto-net-swarm           overlay   swarm
4934f4344622   none                               null      local

>docker network inspect my_stack_ditto-net-swarm

[
    {
        "Name": "my_stack_ditto-net-swarm",
        "Id": "miy4fnbluu70bdc30qcqpyqy9",
        "Created": "2024-06-18T16:46:24.45599018Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.1.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.1.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "22f5721bd207a012953cf4f194abf7ce472ef6b18a6d167df73c4efae26a2ff9": {
                "Name": "my_stack_ditto-ui.1.jcnhcxrkxu9kl8v1a7dwjk4e1",
                "EndpointID": "008daec7000072bb81e7fef018f022a53a86b27a124aa32392c584b3ab479166",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:06",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.6/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "469a013c5ef0ab8c914dbd0aceeecbd522eba314a55648abd0512c0fb844e6c7": {
                "Name": "my_stack_things-search.1.x030dszx0c2kdwpptlmfsybbu",
                "EndpointID": "eb6fb56aa6d6a5b650e057473cb4576faab98aea3407c53564cae38f3de9b16d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:0c",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.12/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "4bba3cf66c010d629b6fd3ecd7467b9f9a85442363e276d18901e6559247d029": {
                "Name": "my_stack_gateway.1.8s3y9sezounm8c0l0sfnp8fcb",
                "EndpointID": "62f02710d5f9bf5b861a86c0a348141607167125c10a977d5c1766ca807b8cc7",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "67b18c17bc245bd547a49c36119f4404d0a15e4d674b681b8bdeb6273aaae364": {
                "Name": "my_stack_policies.1.rbgb8unxtoqqg2l0rhw026ppq",
                "EndpointID": "96a54ba12d049aebbd4d65caa888676ec009a535fa5bdd713a2d9ab873c9ebd2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:0f",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.15/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "92fe4111b89f0e5a890f877d2d69e33bd0be8ce4765a28a1b8bf7e30811d3c65": {
                "Name": "my_stack_swagger-ui.1.xbtbyt3gd63wff5hrph6naj4o",
                "EndpointID": "0265305aa5b16b532e304b8f5557e95996e983bfad04bac7e90949c3459c287b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:0a",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.10/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a46e189a9c4ea4be0bc3cb49213af4d608bdc08995f2f4078d3d287e35333810": {
                "Name": "my_stack_mongodb.1.fsatefqvrmwsyo8yw8tp6qgf6",
                "EndpointID": "1ca0f13f71fc59027ca925be64c3b11c9a13ce9dc1fca56c77f22ef9f1d4913c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:13",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.19/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "abaf31aa0a26d89630dfc90c0e90fd38fb9ea3dab141855f7820e0d5ed75ad3e": {
                "Name": "my_stack_things.1.396rkdghvfvhoxaohkprmyy58",
                "EndpointID": "80c8e0ff38da65c9df9db924325743a49311d6e7211d395e0f62b38bd527b7c8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:15",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.21/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ed73ab9cc3e99314f1e2809fc41eda5c7f700b8f59d129a912cc05659ac73ffa": {
                "Name": "my_stack_connectivity.1.njn438mpqzyhgg16r67mrriar",
                "EndpointID": "4436d51cf549f07aaf777afa9bf8e310e593ad7cde3df9d4f0395f684a78a1f0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:11",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.17/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "efe84e1eec4843608fb5d950a88b0e63dc81247f2420b75fd4b47293610a74b7": {
                "Name": "my_stack_nginx.1.e5c48q82xwb9z8ebapm20pri0",
                "EndpointID": "3bf4e453701f08a584d7fed4e24a6953130553cd5741ebd58dac5934d810d71a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:0d",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.13/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-my_stack_ditto-net-swarm": {
                "Name": "my_stack_ditto-net-swarm-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "ed13713847ca2649c46e0e4ffe5736485a2d96150c9abf596779a3a053d6ccbe",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:04",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4097"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "my_stack"
        },
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "c4f6c67a05a0",
                "IP": "192.168.65.3"
            }
        ]
    }
]

The logs of my_stack_gateway : https://pastebin.com/LJrQX5Hw

Nginx, by default, resolves hostnames in nginx.conf on startup.
This is problematic in swarm as "depends_on" is not available to enforce container startup order, more so because swarm services can be restarted with new IPs.
To get Nginx to resolve service IPs on the fly you need to do two things:

add a resolver 127.0.0.11 directive. Nginx uses the host OS resolver at startup but dynamic dns needs an explicit resolver configured. 127.0.0.11 is the special dns server Docker Swarm implements.

In the nginx.conf file, declare any hostnames as variables using set server="service" and then use $server in your proxy etc config.


http {
    # Define the resolver using the Docker DNS
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;

    server {
        listen 80;
        
        location / {
            set $upstream http://webapp;
            proxy_pass $upstream;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}

